# Java compiler unexpected "incompatible types" error

Tags: java, javac

My Java compiler `javac 1.6.0_37` fails at compiling the following small program:

```
import java.util.*;

public class QueueTest {
    public static void main( String args[] ) {
        Queue<String> q = new LinkedList<String>();
    }
}
```

The error message is:

```
QueueTest.java:5: incompatible types
found   : java.util.LinkedList<java.lang.String>
required: Queue<java.lang.String>
        Queue<String> q = new LinkedList<String>();
                          ^
1 error
```

According to the documentation, `LinkedList<E>` implements `Queue<E>`, and this should compile. I was able to compile this code with `javac 1.5.0_08`. Also, you can take the generics out of the picture and the problem remains the same (it won't compile, even without generics).

My question is: anyone defends the position of this not being a bug?

Comment: Did you try explicitly `java.util.Queue<String> q = new java.util.LinkedList<String>();` ? Maybe you have in current package some other class `Queue<T>` or something and it messes things up?

Comment: Which type of `Queue` object are you using?  Do you have your own `Queue` class implemented?  From the docs, I see no reason that this wouldn't work.

Comment: Note that the required type is `Queue<java.lang.String>`, and not `java.util.Queue<java.lang.String>`. Remove the Queue class you have in your classpath, in the default package. And never, never use the default package.

Comment: Just tried it and it works!! Anyway, it's not obvious to me what is messing things up. I'll try to print the name of the class. Thanks amit!!

Comment: Actually, this happened to me compiling code on Java 8 update 20 that used to compile on Java 7 update 67. My temporary fix was to go back to 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing explicitly:

```
java.util.Queue<String> q = new java.util.LinkedList<String>();
```

Note that when importing with `package.*` it is prone to overriding (if you have a class with the same name that you explicitly imported or in the working package):

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/packages.html#7.5.1):

> A single-type-import declaration d in a compilation unit c of package
>   p that imports a type named n shadows the declarations of:
>
> ```
> any top level type named n declared in another compilation unit of p.
> any type named n imported by a type-import-on-demand declaration in c.
> any type named n imported by a static-import-on-demand declaration in c.
> ```

What you have here is a type-import-on-demand declaration, which is shadowed by a single type import declaration

Comment: Right, I've figured it out now: in my Extensions directory I found algs4.jar and stdlib.jar, which where the libraries for Sedgewick's Algorithms course. I erased them and now everything works OK. Your comment on importing with * also solved other questions I had before. Thanks amit.

Answer (score 4):

It compiles for me.

The only conclusion is that you have imported a `Queue` class other than `java.util.Queue` or imported a `LinkedList` other than `java.util.LinkedList` or both.

Answer (score 2):

There must be some other bug because it [compiles fine with ideone](http://ideone.com/HemUhU) using Java 1.6.0.31:

```
import java.util.*;

class QueueTest {
    public static void main( String args[] ) {
        Queue<String> q = new LinkedList<String>();
    }
}
```

Do you have another class on your classpath such as `java.util.Queue` or `java.util.LinkedList` which is overriding the JDK one?